Adding Show To Element with addEventListener Through index.js file Not Working
I'm trying to add 'show' to a class in order to toggle a sidebar but, the sidebar is not showing up. I assume it has something to do with the imports since I can add 'show' to the class and it will show normally. I updated the code so it includes toggle-nav. The button does show in the navbar. Unfortunately, the functionality is not working. Here is the code for reference:
import './src/toggleSidebar.js';
import './src/cart/toggleCart.js';
import './src/cart/setupCart.js';

import { getElement } from "./utils.js";

const toggleNav = getElement(".toggle-nav");
const sidebarOverlay = getElement(".sidebar-overlay");
const closeBtn = getElement(".sidebar-close");

toggleNav.addEventListener("click", () => {
  sidebarOverlay.classList.add("show");
});
closeBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  sidebarOverlay.classList.remove("show");
});

 <nav class="navbar">
      <div class="nav-center">
        <div class="logo-with-nav">
          <button class="toggle-nav">
            <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
          </button>
          <div class="logo">
            <ul>
              <li>
                <a href="index.html" class="nav-link-logo"> Tealaxation </a>
                <img
                  src="./images/TealaxationLogo.png"
                  class="nav-logo"
                  alt="logo"
                />
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>

          <ul class="nav-links">
            <li>
              <a href="about.html" class="nav-link"> About </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="products.html" class="nav-link"> Shop </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="locations.html" class="nav-link"> Locations </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>

  <!-- sidebar -->
    <div class="sidebar-overlay">
      <aside class="sidebar">
        <!-- close -->
        <button class="sidebar-close">
          <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
        </button>
        <!-- links -->
        <ul class="sidebar-links">
          <li>
            <a href="index.html" class="sidebar-link">
              <i class="fas fa-home fa-fw"></i>
              home
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="products.html" class="sidebar-link">
              <i class="fas fa-couch fa-fw"></i>
              products
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="about.html" class="sidebar-link">
              <i class="fas fa-book fa-fw"></i>
              about
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </aside>
    </div>


Your code here does not contain all the elements you are attempting to retrieve (.toggle-nav). Please include all relevant code.

Are there any errors in your dev console? When you inspect the code after clicking, does the classname display on the expected element? Running a simplified version of your code without the imports, using the show class to change the background, seems to work fine.

Make sure the JavaScript that adds the event listeners runs after the DOM is loaded. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element
